# Fucntion is abolutely continuous if its derivative is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in C^1 [a, b]$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq M, ∀ x$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous.

I have no clue how to proceed. I tried to get a cover for abs. continuity bout couldn't do it.

EDIT : From carmichael561 's hint I have tried the foloowing. 
Applying MVT to f 
we get $f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ and $|f'c()| \leq M$ now consider a partition of interval $[a,b]$ as $a=p_0 < p_1 < ... < p_n = b$ now apply MVT to each of these small intervals. 
now if $\sum_1^n l((p_i,p_{i+1})) \leq \delta $ then $\sum_1^n |f(p_{i+1}) -f(p_i) | \leq M \delta$

Is this fine ?

Comment: Do you mean $|f^{\prime}|\leq M$? I'd try using the mean value theorem

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the derivative is bounded by $M$ then by the mean value theorem, $f$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $M$. For $\epsilon > 0$, take $a \le x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n \le b$ with $$\sum^n_{k=1} (x_{k} - x_{k-1}) < \epsilon /M.$$  Then $$\sum^n_{k=1} \lvert f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1}) \rvert \le \sum^n_{k=1} M (x_k - x_{k-1}) = M \sum^n_{k=1} (x_k - x_{k-1}) < M\cdot \epsilon / M = \epsilon$$ which shows that $f$ is absolutely continuous.

To prove the first claim, for any $x < y \in [a,b]$, then by the mean value theorem, there is $c \in (x,y)$ such that $$\lvert f(x) -f(y)\rvert  = \lvert f'(c) \rvert (x-y) \le M(x-y),$$ showing that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $M$.

Comment: Thanks. Saw your answer after editing my post. Now its all clear to me from your detailed explaination.